# Can I use environment-specific variables in EF manual migrations?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration

#### Background

- My project is using Entity Framework
- Migrations are being deployed via OctopusDeploy by using the `migrate.exe` executable

#### Problem / Goal

I need to script a set of permissions to the database for an account on each system, e.g.

- When deployed to dev, `account1` must be granted datareader/datawriter access
- When deployed to test, `account2` must be granted datareader/datawriter access.
- etc.

I'd like to use the same system for this that we're using so far (manual code-based migrations). If possible, I'd like to script the permission grants for a database and run them as part of our migrate.exe execution on deployment.

However, because I'll only have one "migration" that applies these permissions, I don't know to ensure I apply the right permissions to the right user in each environment.

#### Questions

- Is there a recommended way to know or apply which environment the migrations are a part of when running migrate.exe so that I can run it against all environments without issue?
- Can I pass in some sort of variable to migrate.exe which I can then use in my migrations?
- Is there something wrong in my premise / assumptions when approaching this?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear.  Are you asking how to install the same app multiple times using different permissions each time, or using a different set of permissions every time you do a migration?  The first is probably best handled by an OS setting, the second wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Claies thanks for responding and good feedback; I had originally written the question on mobile and it was definitely not detailed enough. I've re-written; please let me know if the clarifications make sense.